# Как обратиться к элементам класса в теле обработчика HTML-элемента

Tags: javascript, классы, onclicklistener

```
class Cell {
    constructor() {
        this.element.onclick = this.turnStateCell;
    }

    turnStateCell() {
        if(this.checked) {
            this.checked = false; // нужно обратиться к Cell, но обращается к Cell.element
        }
        else {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что через `this` идёт обращение к `this.element`, но мне надо, чтобы он обращался к `this` (к самому себе).

Comment: Откуда класс `Cell` узнает об this.element?

Comment: Но все равно можно взять и написать так: `this.element.onclick = this.turnStateCell.bind(this);` и уже `this` будет указывать на   `Cell`

Comment: @Adrug помогло!